# Llamar desde vista a métodos de un controlador

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-blade

soy nuevo en Iaravel y he creado una aplicación de espectáculos, He creado un CRUD con los metodos restfull creo que se llaman, y todo funciona ok, he creado una plantilla donde muestro dinamicamente los diferentes espectaculos con el metodo show, y hace lo que quiero. y con el metodo index los gestiono en una tabla con editar y eliminar. Bien, necesito mostrar los espectaculos (El titulo) en el menu principal (app.blade.php), para asi poder añadir las paginas dinamicamente. ¿Como llamo desde la vista a un metodo del controlador? lo he puesto static y no se si es buena practica, como se realiza en laravel esta accion.
el metodo del controlador:

```
public static function getAllWorks()
{
    // recibo todos los eventos
    $works = Work::all();

    return $works;
}
```

Lo quiero mostrar aquí con algo así

```
@foreach($works as $work)
 <li>
    <a href="#">{{ $work->title() }}</a>
 </li>
@endforeach
```

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: ¿Podrías mostrarnos tu método que recibe la petición? ¿por qué no pasas el parametro a la vista desde el controlador?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si necesitas mostrar datos en una vista, previamente debes hacer disponibles esos datos para la vista. Lo normal sería que la vista se cargue desde un controlador, que hace disponibles esos datos para la vista. También es posible obtenerlos directamente en las rutas y *flasearlos* para su carga en la vista, pero no es lo recomendable.

Supongo que lo que tienes en tu fichero de rutas es algo como lo que viene por defecto:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
   return view('app');
});
```

y necesitas los datos en la vista que estás cargando.

Puedes invocar un método de un controlador en su lugar que cargue los datos y devuelva la vista. Pongamos que tienes los tatos en la tabla "works".

Código en las rutas

```
Route::get(
   'app', 
   [
      'as'   => 'app',
      'uses' => 'AppController@show'
   ]
));
```

Y en AppController:

```
public function show() {

    $data = \DB::select('SELECT title FROM works');

    return view( 'app' )
        ->with( 'works', $data )
}
```

Y en tu template:

```
@foreach($works as $work)
 <li>
    <a href="#">{{ $works->title }}</a>
 </li>
@endforeach
```

La otra forma, es que obtengas los datos directamente en las rutas:

```
Route::get(
   'app', 
   function () {

      $data = DB::select('SELECT title FROM works');

      return View::make('app')
         ->with( 'works', $data )
   }
);
```

Y en el template, lo mismo que en el otro ejemplo.

Answer (score 0):

He aplicado esta solución, no sé si es una buena practica, ya que he leido que debo pasar por el controlador. 
Este es el codigo que he usado:

```
@foreach(\App\Work::all() as $work)
    <li><a href="{{route('works.show', $work->id)}}">{{$work->title}}</a></li>
@endforeach
```

Comment: En definitiva es una mala practica, porque te sales del concepto MVC, se supone que debes pasarle a la vista todo lo que la vista necesita, por eso debes llamar el metodo en el controlador y luego le pasas ese parámetro a la vista.

Answer (score 0):

El problema que me encuentro es que al cambiar de pagina, no reconoce la variable, ya que el menu es comun para todas las vistas.

¿Como puedo hacer para solucionarlo?

Comment: Deberías poner `work.show` en lugar de `works.show`